# How to remove a temporary NSManagedObjectContext created for editing purpose

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

in an iOS COreData app, I gave a try to temporary context used only for editing of object.

I discarded the parentContext introduced with iOS 5 because of being buggy, so it is just a normal context with the usual save notification mechanism for merging with the main context.

This seems to work, however I am not sure of a point:

I have a factory which build the context for me, rather than passing from controller to controller. The temporary context serves only for editing purpose, and because I am not editing entities all the time, my understanding (perhaps wrong) is that it has to be removed as soon as the work is complete to free resources.

So to reassume, how to remove the temporary context ? Or do it need to stay around for later reuse ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC, all you have to do is make sure nothing is referencing the MOC.  In other words, if you keep a pointer to it somewhere, set it to nil.  Otherwise, the MOC should get destroyed readily enough when you stop referencing it.

Several easy ways to make sure...

1. In instruments, trace the MOC objects to see when they are alloc/dealloc.
2. Subclass `NSManagedObjectContext` and just override init/dealloc -- make sure to call into super -- except for dealloc -- in ARC that will not work.  You can then trace it
3. Set a breakpoint at -[NSManagedObjectContext dealloc] and see it go away
4. Add an associated object (via `objc_setAssociatedObject`) that has a dealloc so you can see when the MOC is deallocated
5. Set a __weak reference to the MOC and observe it going to nil
6. Many other options...

Bottom line is that there are many ways to "track" your MOC getting destroyed (or not).

If you are using ARC, all you have to do is make sure no other objects hold a reference to your MOC, and it will just go away into the sunset like all other objects.

My #1 suggestion is the only one I have ordered by preference.  If you already know how to use Instruments, this will be a piece of cake.

If you don't know how to use instruments, then you definitely should use option #1 because I do not know of a single more valuable development tool (other than the compiler itself) for developing on Apple's platforms..

-- Of course, the same thing applies when not using ARC -- but you have to manually get the refcount stuff right.

Answer (score 0):

I've written this short code that takes care of propagating the context changes to other contexts:

Assuming:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary* threadsDictionary;
```

Here is how to get the managed object (per thread):

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContextForThread {

// Per thread, give one back
NSString* threadName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[NSThread currentThread].hash];

NSManagedObjectContext * existingContext = [self.threadsDictionary objectForKey:threadName];
if (existingContext==nil){
    existingContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [existingContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    [self.threadsDictionary setValue:existingContext forKey:threadName];
}

return existingContext;
```

}

At some point in the init method of your global manager (I used a singleton):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:)                                                    name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification                                                   object:nil];
```

Then to receive save notifications and propagate to all other managed context objects:

```
- (void)backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
    /* Make sure we're on the main thread when updating the main context */
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:)
                               withObject:notification
                            waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }

    /* merge in the changes to the main context */
    for (NSManagedObjectContext* context in [self.threadsDictionary allValues]){
            [context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

(some other methods were removed for clarity)